# LED changing colour over time

Tags: led, colour

Can a LED change colour over time?

I've had a blue LED set up for some time and it use to be a much brighter (ultramarine blue) now it's heading to a more greenish dull colour.  How is this happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is over-voltage or over-current, both of which can be caused by using an incorrect resistor with the LED, or by a power supply giving more voltage than you thought. Slightly overdriving a LED will often work at first, but it will wear it out much sooner than if the specs were followed.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, not all LEDs are well made, and some will deteriorate over time even without mishandling. How long have you had this LED running? If it's just a few hundred hours, it probably was damaged by something, but if it has been in use for thousands of hours, it may just be aging.